# Does python compile_command consider the environment?

Tags: python

The document says the `compile_command` function in the `code` module will return a valid code object if the user input is **"complete and valid"**. I would like to know whether this decision is dependent on the running environment of python, such as on the variables and the imported modules in the workspace which runs `compile_command`.

The reason I'm asking this is because I want to send a user input from a python in my local machine to a python in a remote machine for execution. I would like to decide whether the user input is complete before actually sending it for execution. My question is, does it suffice to call `compile_command` in my local machine, or do I have to send the user input to the remote machine to decide whether it is complete or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Compiling is independent from the execution environment. This is why `compile_command` does not take *globals* and *locals* parameters like the [`eval()` function](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#eval) does.

So, compiling Python code makes sure it is syntactically correct and that it follows the rules of the language. However, this makes no guarantee that the code will actually run when given a particular execution environment.